# How to propagate satellite to orbit intersection (relative node) in GMAT?

Tags: astrodynamics, gmat

I am trying to propagate the spacecraft to the intersection points of two orbits (relative node) in GMAT. The analytical calculations of the true anomaly of that point is done using the formulas in general plane change maneuver but when I try this value in GMAT, the spacecraft either moves a bit up or lower than the intersection point. Is there any solution to this problem?

Secondly, why does GMAT changes AOP when we propagate (i have tried keeping all perturbations OFF but still the problem persists)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A stopping condition on the true anomaly should work. How large is the difference you're seeing between your calculation and where GMAT stops? There are possibly multiple reasons for this.

First, it can be difficult to remove all perturbations in the GMAT script: can you update your question with the script you're using? The AOP should not vary if all perturbations are turned off.

Second, GMAT uses the secant method to converge on an event: depending on the shape and inclination of your orbit, the true anomaly might be ill-defined at the location of the intersection, thereby making it difficult to actually converge onto the point you're seeking.